# ES6 React bind on change

Tags: reactjs

Working on a dashboard and I need to update the table when I change the period (i.e. Month, Quarter, etc) when the option changes. Having trouble w/ the bindings.

```
export default class SalesFinancialDiv extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {periods: null, period: null};
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        $.getJSON("/marketing-dashboard/sales-financial/periods", function(result) {
            this.setState({periods: result, period: result[1]});
        }.bind(this));
    }

    onChange(event) {
        console.log(event.target.value);
        this.setState({period: event.target.value});
    }

    render() {
        if(this.state.periods != null && this.state.period != null) {
            return (
                <div>
                    <h3>Marketing Dashboard | Financial Data</h3>
                    <SalesFinancialPeriods periods={this.state.periods} onChange={this.onChange} />
                    <SalesFinancialTable period={this.state.period} />
                </div>
            );
        } else {
            return (
                <div>Loading...</div>
            );
        }
    }
}

class SalesFinancialPeriods extends React.Component {
    makeOptions(data) {
        return (
            data.map(function(period) {
                return (
                    <option value={period}>{period}</option>
                )
            })
        );
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div id="sales-financial-periods">
                <select onChange={this.props.onChange} >
                    {this.makeOptions(this.props.periods)}
                </select>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class SalesFinancialTable extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <table className="table table-striped table-codero">
                <TableHeader />
                <TableBody  period={this.props.period} />
                <TableFooter />
            </table>
        );
    }
}

class TableBody extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {data: null, dates: null};
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        let url1 = "/marketing-dashboard/sales-financial/data/" + this.props.period;
        let url2 = "/marketing-dashboard/sales-financial/dates/" + this.props.period;
        $.getJSON(url1, function(result) {
            this.setState({data: result});
        }.bind(this));
        $.getJSON(url2, function(result) {
            this.setState({dates: result});
        }.bind(this));

    }
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        let url1 = "/marketing-dashboard/sales-financial/data/" + nextProps.period;
        let url2 = "/marketing-dashboard/sales-financial/dates/" + nextProps.period;
        $.getJSON(url1, function(result) {
            this.setState({data: result});
        }.bind(this));
        $.getJSON(url2, function(result) {
            this.setState({dates: result});
        }.bind(this));

    }
    render() {
        // 
    }
}
```

As you can see the highest level class `SalesFinancialDiv` fires off and gets the `periods` and the initial `period` it then passes the periods to the `SalesFinancialPeriods` class that builds the dropdown. Also `SalesFinancialDiv` passes the initial `period` down two children to the `TableBody` which fires off to get the data to populate the table.

As I said I need to figure out how to pass the new selected period off to the `TableBody` class to fire off and get the new set of data.

**Updated** Changed `<select>` to `<select onChange={this.props.onChange}>` and I am now seeing the change in the parent node but I am not seeing the parent node pass the new `period` to the children. Coworker and I thought since the highest level node is being updated w/ `setState` it would re-render children. Also checked to see if the `xhr` request was sent and it was not.

**Update 2** implemented `componentWillReceiveProps` and fixed issue! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [React Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentdidmount):

> **Mounting: componentDidMount**
>
> `void componentDidMount()`
>
> Invoked once,
>   only on the client (not on the server), immediately after the initial
>   rendering occurs. At this point in the lifecycle, you can access any
>   refs to your children (e.g., to access the underlying DOM
>   representation). The componentDidMount() method of child components is
>   invoked before that of parent components.

So the **componentDidMount** is called only once in the lifecycle just after initial rendering happen - with your current setup there will be no more AJAX calls till you hit refresh.

You will have to thinker around using [ComponentWillReceiveProps](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentwillreceiveprops) otherwise **$.getJSON(...)** is being called only once.

**PS**

You should probably look into some flux implementation as making AJAX requests from inside of the components will cause you a lot of issues. I recomend Redux.

Comment: This appeared to be the correct solution. Added what worked to the the original post. Thank you @Kocur4d

Comment: Updated with small ps

Comment: Saw that. Coworker uses that and I've been looking into it. Just started using React 2-3 weeks ago.